# Laravel - Missing required parameters for [Route: edit] [URI: cruds/{agency}/{id}/edit]

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've a problem with route and parameters, in particular I'm trying to pass two variables. I've to edit a point {idPost} in an agency {idAgency}.
My controller is

```
public function change($agency,$id)
{
    $crud = Description::find($id);
    $impl = Implementation::find($id);
    return view('cruds.edit',compact('crud','impl','id'));
}
```

called in view as

```
<a href="{{ action('CrudsController@change',$agency['id'],$post['id']) }}">
  <button id="modifica" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Modifica</button>
</a>
```

and my route is

```
Route::get('cruds/{agency}/{id}/edit',['as'=>'edit','uses'=>'CrudsController@change']);
```

I've looked for solution a lot before to ask but I haven't found anything good for me. I'm sorry. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

Please change your **Anchor** tag

```
<a href="{{ url('cruds',[$agency['id'],$post['id']]) }}">
  <button id="modifica" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Modifica</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've changed my route as


Route::get('cruds/edit/{id}/{agency}/',['as'=>'edit','uses'=>'CrudsController@change']);

and my anchor tag as


<a href="{{ url('cruds/edit',[$agency['id'],$post['id]]) }}>

Thank you again!

Comment: @RossiMario : Glad to help